# how to pass a context to a custom defined method in groovy?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

```
def setSystemProperties(project) {
    if (project.hasProperty('serverversion')) {
        args(serverversion)
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('input_flavor')) {
        systemProperties['input_flavor'] = input_flavor
        print "gradle input_flavor" + input_flavor
    }
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}



//warm up

task BL_generate_parallel_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
    setSystemProperties(project)
    dependsOn resources_cleaner_bl
    systemProperties['isDummyRun'] = 'true'
    main = "astar.BlParallelGenerator"
}
```

what context should I pass to my `setSystemProperties()` to fix this error?

`> No such property: jvmArgs for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated`

or 
`> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [file collection] on root project 'RoutingRegression'.`

the code worked fine when it was all in the the task body:

```
//warm up

task BL_generate_parallel_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
      if (project.hasProperty('serverversion')) {
        args(serverversion)
    }
    if (project.hasProperty('input_flavor')) {
        systemProperties['input_flavor'] = input_flavor
        print "gradle input_flavor" + input_flavor
    }
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    dependsOn resources_cleaner_bl
    systemProperties['isDummyRun'] = 'true'
    main = "astar.BlParallelGenerator"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your task I see why the classpath setting is failing. Your missing the `=`.  With an equals sign it means your setting a property of the `JavaExec` class instance.  Without an equals sign then you are telling groovy to call a method.  Since no method exists `setClasspath` (classpath only exists as a property of the class), the method fails.

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'example.so.35869599.Main'
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
    // arguments to pass to the application
    args 'blah!'
}
```

Using the above I'm able to run a test class that contains `public static void main(String... args)` method

Reference to the `jvmArgs` in `JavaExec` can be found here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:jvmArgs

Edit: Didn't notice you were trying to pass the `JavaExec` object around.  The instance of `JavaExec` is passed as an arg to the `JavaExec` configuration closure.  We can make that a little clearer with an example like this.

```
// here if we specify the type and name of the object passed to the closure
// it becomes clearer where we can access the `jvmArgs` property.
task runApp(type: JavaExec) { JavaExec exec ->
    addArgsToJvm(exec)
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'example.so.35869599.Main'
    // arguments to pass to the application
    args 'appArg1'
}

def addArgsToJvm(JavaExec exec) {
    println "############################## caller passed: ${exec.getClass().getCanonicalName()}"
    exec.jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m", "-Xmx1024m"]
}
```

The above example would show this result in the command line:

```
############################## caller passed: org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec_Decorated
```